# Conditionally exclude model fields from response or best practice to achieve it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I have this code to demonstrate my desired results.

```
[HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(200)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll([FromQuery] Boolean includeData = false)
    {
        if (includeData)
        {
            var processListWithData = new List<ProcessWithData>()
            {
                new ProcessWithData() {Id = "1", Key = "k-1", Data = "Data1"},
                new ProcessWithData() {Id = "2", Key = "k-2", Data = "Data2"},
                new ProcessWithData() {Id = "3", Key = "k-3", Data = "Data3"}
            };
            return Ok(processListWithData);
        }
        else
        {
            var processList = new List<Process>()
            {
                new Process() {Id = "11", Key = "k-11"},
                new Process() {Id = "22", Key = "k-22"},
                new Process() {Id = "33", Key = "k-33"}
            };
            return Ok(processList);
        }


    }
```

If you set the query parameter includeData to true, the results will include the data field. If you set it to false, it will not include the data field in the results.

Is there a way to achieve the desired result without having to use 2 different objects that will be returned?

Comment: I would recommend you to use only one model. If you get the request to not include data do `Data = null` once you have only one object you can change your action to reflect that, it should be something like this: `public async Task<ProcessWithData> GetAll` that way swashbuckle can show the  correct response